# Google Ad Manager (not 360) no connector to Google Data Studio

Tags: google-data-studio, google-ad-manager

Does Google Ad Manager (not 360) have a Google Data Studio connector?
Their page here is subtly ambiguous
https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7558019?hl=en

Comment: The page you linked says "Only available in Google Ad Manager 360."     That doesn't sound so ambiguous to me.   Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: well the bit at the top is aligned with the help section (which can be interpretted as help being for 360 users which is a common thing Google does), and then again where it mentions it halfway down the page it is only for one facet of the overall page

Answer (score 0):

There are a many third-parties that provide a Google ad manager connector for Google data studio.  In any case, I'm not sure a native connector would be preferable because Google tends to lack of customer support.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll consider those.